# Using the jquery plugin SpriteSpin how can I get the image to spin to a certain frame on button click?

Tags: jquery, plugins, onclicklistener, rangeslider, 360-degrees

I am trying to get my image to spin to a certain frame when a button is clicked using sprite spin plugin.

Here is the plugin Docs I am using -

```
http://spritespin.ginie.eu/samples/#/misc-slider
```

I don't see a built in function for this so I am trying to programmatically manipulate a range slider to navigate the the correct image I want to display.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/spritespin@4.0.11/release/spritespin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div class="spritespin"></div>
<input class="spritespin-slider" type="range">

<button>Click Me</button>
```

And here is the JS -

```
$(function() {
    $('.spritespin').spritespin({
source: SpriteSpin.sourceArray('/sandbox/sprite/img/gem{frame}.jpg', { frame: [1,7], digits: 1 }),
    width: 480,
    height: 327,
    sense: 1,
    animate: false,
    plugins: [
      '360'
    ],
    onFrame: function(e, data) {
       $('.spritespin-slider').val(data.frame)
    },
    onInit: function(e, data) {
       $('.spritespin-slider')
        .attr("min", 0)
        .attr("max", data.source.length - 1)
        .attr("value", 0)
        .on("input", function(e) {
           SpriteSpin.updateFrame(data, e.target.value);
        })
    }
  });
});
```

At this point the image spins with the range slider and everything works as it should. I try and add a click function and update the range value which it does but the image does not spin and/or update at all. When I inspect the range input I see the values are updating but im guessing I need to use the SpriteSpin.updateFrame but not sure how to do that.

Here is my JS click function to update the range -

```
var btn = document.querySelector("button");
var slider = document.querySelector("input[type='range']");

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    slider.value = 3;
});
```

I have a total of 7 images and am trying to get the image to spin to frame 3 on click.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer, they do offer a function to stopFrame.

```
frame:0, // Start frame
stopFrame: 3, // End frame
```